# Probability Mass Function Problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here is a problem that I cannot seem to understand:

> A storage carousel has 100 equally sized storage locations. The picker
> has just finished removing the requested item from that location. The
> carousel is about to rotate to the next needed location. Suppose the
> length of time it takes to rotate n locations is $1.5n$ seconds.
> Assume that each of the other 99 locations is equally likely to be
> next location needed by the picker. Let $T = 1.5N$ be the number of
> seconds needed to rotate to the next needed location.
>
> $(a)$ Assuming the carousel can only rotate clockwise, what is the $p.m.f.$ (probability mass function) of $N$?
>
> $(b)$ Assuming the carousel can only rotate clockwise, what is the $p.m.f.$ of $T$?
>
> $(c)$ If the carousel is bi-directional, what is the p.m.f. of N?

To me, it seems like the answer to $(a)$ would be that each location has a probability of $\frac{1}{99}$ for each value of $n$. Moreover, for $(b)$, the p.m.f would be $\frac{1.5}{99}$.

This is my best attempt at an answer, and I have gone through multiple textbooks to try and find the answer, and my answer does not seem to be the apparent one. I have absolutely no idea how to approach $(c)$, because to me it doesn't seem to make a difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a): What are the values that $N$ can take? Enumerate these (or a few of them), and manually compute the probability that $N$ takes that value.

> $N$ can only take integer values. If the carousel is at spot $0$, and the next spot is spot $1$, then it takes $1.5$ seconds to get there; hence, $N=1$, and so forth... In such a case, $N$ represents the relative index of the next spot vis-a-vis the current spot, so each $N$ should have a $\frac{1}{99}$ chance.

For (b): do the same. Note: there are 99 different possible outcomes. If the pmf is $\frac{1.5}{99}$, then what is the sum of of the PMF over all possible values? What would be wrong with this sum?

> There are 99 unique durations: 1.5 sec, 3 sec, etc. This is exactly the same as part (a).

For (c): Again, enumerate all possible values. How many spots are exactly 1 step away? How many are exactly two steps away? And so on...

Now, for simplicity, I'm assuming that the carousel can go both directions, but once it picks a direction, it goes that way. So it doesn't go CW->CCW back to its starting position. Otherwise the problem becomes much harder... ;)

Comment: Also assume that the carousel controller is optimal: it won't go 99 steps in one direction, if it can simply go 1 step in the other.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Arkamis! I really appreciate the help.